# Trying to run granadanet node, receives invalid data directory error

Tags: tezos-client, testnet

I'm following the procedure described in the [documentation](https://tezos.gitlab.io/introduction/howtoget.html) to run a granadanet node.

In my docker containers, specifically `granadanet_node_1` and `granadanet_upgrader_1`, I'm stuck with the following error while they keep restarting to no avail:

```
Nov 22 10:46:22.748 - node.main: FULL access to RPC enabled; this is very risky. (addresses = :8732)
tezos-node: Error: Invalid data directory '/var/run/tezos/node/data': Please provide a clean directory by removing the following files: lock.
```

For the sake of testing, I have created the said directory in my drive and set chmoded it to 777.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: FYI, Granada will be dead in about 2 weeks when Tezos activates Hangzhou2 on Dec 3. You should be testing on Hangzhounet test net.

Comment: @utdrmac thanks for the heads-up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message quite clearly states, you need to stop the container and remove the `lock` file inside the data directory. Did you bind-mount external directories into your container or just using default storage? Please show us the entire command you used.

Comment: That was my issue, has developed in your answer. 

I was using the default storage and did not remove the lock file within it. I was wrongly assuming I had bind-mount external directories. 

It's now working as expected, thank you very much.